# How to create DASH manifest url for youtube videos?

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am creating android application. I want to play Youtube videos in the exoplayer.
In the exoplayer demo app all the url's are stored in media.exolist.json like this:

```
 {
    "uri": "https://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/bf5bb2419360daf1/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0",
    "extension": "mpd"
  }
```

I want to know how to create this manifest dash url for my youtube videos.